# Einen Webservice "einbinden", "anbinden" oder "einbauen"

Tags: word-choice

Wäre interessant, ob ich richtig folgende Verbe benutze:

> Die Abteilung hat den Webservice schon eingebunden.

oder

> Die Abteilung hat den Webservice schon angebunden.

klingt schräg für mich, aber vielleicht wird's auch gebraucht?
oder

> Die Abteilung hat den Webservice schon eingebaut.

Es geht um informelle Sprache. Hinweise auf Unterschiede sind willkommen.

Comment: Angebunden klingt für mich wie Kabel eingesteckt. Aber ich bin kein Informatiker ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das kommt wohl auf die genaue technische Natur des Webservices an und wie er verwendet wird.

- Ein Webservice wie Google Apis, Google Site Analytics, Facebook oder Twitter wird *eingebunden* oder *eingebaut*. Es kommt ja *in* die bestehende Seite. *Angebunden* finde ich da unpassend.
- Wenn ich einen anderen Server serverseitig per z. B. REST befragte, dann wäre *angebunden* passend, letztlich spräche ich aber doch eher von *eingebaut*, denn ich habe es ja in den Code eingebaut wie ein Teil in eine Maschine. *Eingebunden* wäre auch möglich.

Letztlich hat das etwas damit zu tun, was für eine Vorstellung man selber davon hat - will ich betonen, dass etwas eingebaut wurde wie ein Bauteil, eingebunden, dass es verwoben ist, oder angebunden, dass vor allem eine Verbindung zwischen "uns" und "denen" besteht, wir aber von denen abhängig sind.

Answer (score 2):

*eingebunden* bzw. *angebunden* bedeuten meiner Meinung nach dasselbe, wobei ich eher zu *angebunden* tendiere. Es wurde ja eine Anbindung an einen Webservice realisiert, soweit ich das richtig verstanden habe.

*eingebaut* klingt eher nach der Umsetzung/Implementierung eines Webservices selbst, d.h. das irgendein Dienst nun eine Webanbindung bekommen hat.